# std::unordered_map undeclared identifier using Visual C++ 2008

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2008, unordered-map

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <unordered_map>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    unordered_map< int, string > m;

    m[1] = "one";   
    m[2] = "two";
    m[4] = "four";
    m[3] = "three";
    m[2] = "TWO!";
    cout << m[2] << endl;

    m.clear();
    return 0;
}
```

I am learning and can't figure it out. The compiler throws the error that type `unordered_map` is undeclared.

I am using Visual C++ 2008 Express Edition.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

In Visual Studio 2008 the classes in Technical Report 1 (TR1) are in namespace **std::tr1**.
Add:

```
using namespace std::tr1;
```

to your code.

Comment: Thanks, absolutly fine Coda, It works.So thats what I was missing+1

Answer (score 9):

In the **TR1** `unordered_map` is available from the `<tr1/unordered_map>` header file as `std::tr1::unordered_map`.

In the upcoming **C++0x** standard it is available from the `<unordered_map>` header file as `std::unordered_map`.

so you should use `<tr1/unordered_map>` header and `std::tr1::unordered_map` namespace for vc 2008 because vc 2008 does not support C++0x.

To answer the problem you quoted in comment.
Also, Make sure you download the **[feature pack for VS2008](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=d466226b-8dab-445f-a7b4-448b326c48e7&displaylang=en)**!

Check under new features supported list.

```
New containers (tuple, array, unordered set, etc)
```

Comment: +1 for the appropriate suggestion, but still there is one error-->fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'tr1/unordered_map': No such file or directory

Answer (score 4):

Visual C++ 2008 declares `unordered_map` in namespace `std::tr1`, not in `std`. See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb982522(VS.90).aspx, section *Requirements*.

Answer (score 2):

Your code is working as intended in VS2010. With output of TWO! if that is what you are not getting. May be you should switch to VC++ 2010 Express Edition.
Probably VC++ 2008 does not include TR1

Answer (score 1):

In C++03, `unordered_map` is defined in `std::tr1` namespace (if its defined at all).

So you should use:

```
std::tr1::unordered_map<int, std::string> m;
```

Answer (score -1):

Perhaps you are looking for `stdext::hash_map` instead (included in `<hash_map>`)?

VC++ 2008 express to my knowledge does not include TR1.

Comment: Where does it say that it works with express edition?  I just tried installing it hoping to be wrong, but it fails.  Since the question states express specifically I assumed TR1 must be absent.